# Search for a record by date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a textbox which whenever a textchanged event happens, the function will use the textbox text to search through the database to find the right records.

For example: I have 3 rows (name, phone number, birthday - the format is year - month - day - in SQL Server):

| Name | PhoneNumber | Birthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 482 | 2000-7-9 |
| Dennis | 912 | 2001-12-9 |
| Mike | 123 | 2000-4-1 |

If the textbox.text is `9` or `9/`, I want to return the 2 rows for John and Dennis.

| Name | PhoneNumber | Birthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 482 | 2000-7-9 |
| Dennis | 912 | 2001-12-9 |

It is easy to search if I enter the date with `yyyy-MM-dd` format to the textbox, the query will be:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM   database 
 WHERE  birthday LIKE %textbox.text%
```

I tried and it worked perfectly, but only when the date in textbox is following the `yyyy-MM-day` format. Is there anyway for it to work with the `dd/month/yyyy` format?

Comment: So the data is formatted `yyyy-MM-d` and you want to be able to enter your search term like `dd-MM-yyyy`? And you're using sql server?

Comment: @BeRT2me Yup 

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a formatted string? If it were a proper `date` things get much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comment this should meet your need. NB the months must be double digit: `9/1` will match `9/11` but not `9/01`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE data_base (
>     name VARCHAR (25),
>     id int,
>     birthday date);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into data_base values
> ('John', 482, '2000-7-9'),
> ('Dennis', 912, '2001-12-9'),
> ('Mike', 123, '2000-4-1');
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> declare @textboxtext VARCHAR(25);
> set @textboxtext = '09/07/2000'
> select * 
> from data_base 
> where 
> convert(varchar(10),birthday,103) 
> like CONCAT (@textboxtext,'%');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name |  id | birthday  
> :--- | --: | :---------
> John | 482 | 2000-07-09
> ```

> ```
> declare @textboxtext VARCHAR(25);
> set @textboxtext = '9/'
> select * 
> from data_base 
> where 
> convert(varchar(10),birthday,103) 
> like CONCAT ('%',@textboxtext,'%');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name   |  id | birthday  
> :----- | --: | :---------
> John   | 482 | 2000-07-09
> Dennis | 912 | 2001-12-09
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d948870ba68505b219b1ade5b121d3e8)*

Answer (score 0):

The following queries show how to search using different formatting options for the value given as a 'date'.
You could construct your query with several conditions  `WHERE ... OR ...` to match all cases.
I've changed the name of the table because database is a reserved word.
NB you should not construct your queries directly, to avoid SQL injection. Look up the safe way to do it for the language you are using.

> ```
> declare @textboxtext VARCHAR(25);
> set @textboxtext = '/9'
> select * 
> from data_base 
> where day(birthday) 
> LIKE replace(@textboxtext,'/','');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name   |  id | birthday  
> :----- | --: | :---------
> John   | 482 | 2000-07-09
> Dennis | 912 | 2001-12-09
> ```

> ```
> declare @textboxtext VARCHAR(25);
> set @textboxtext = '09/07/2000'
> select * 
> from data_base 
> where birthday 
>  = convert(date,@textboxtext,103);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name |  id | birthday  
> :--- | --: | :---------
> John | 482 | 2000-07-09
> ```

> ```
> declare @textboxtext VARCHAR(25);
> set @textboxtext = '07/09/2000'
> select * 
> from data_base 
> where birthday 
>  = convert(date,@textboxtext,101) ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name |  id | birthday  
> :--- | --: | :---------
> John | 482 | 2000-07-09
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c3fe5f2c94a416136f64e1e34af0b83)*

Comment: Hey, ty you for answered but that not really what in my mind, I want the query will be execute whenever a text changed event happen in the textbox, like when i type 9, the two rows of John and Dennis will appear, but if i type two more character, '9/1' now only Dennis row will appear because his birthday is 9/12,  and I type 1 more character, '9/11' or '9/1/' no rows will returned cuz no birthday is matched

Comment: Updating the options as you type is client side. What programming language are you using?

Comment: .NET Window Form App